# Remove "add to cart" button with Category Design Layout XML?

Tags: magento, magento2

I'd like to be able to put a snippet of XML within the "Layout Update XML" input and have it pull the "add to cart" button from all the products underneath that category?

[Category Design Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFKC1.png)

EDIT: I have tried the following code within the custom layout XML input with no success.

```html
<reference name="content">
  <remove name="product.info.addtocart"/>
</reference>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @Skoua I have edited my post to reflect what I have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Now this is specific to the project I am working on, but is an interesting way to manage cart options.

I was able to pull the "Add to cart" button by using the Out of Stock feature. I simply have to make the products I don't wish to show out of stock and poof the add to cart button is gone. This gives me the ability to mark certain products to show them off yet not let someone buy them as they need to contact us for said products.